# Swift NsdateFormatter issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'"
let dateShow = formatter.dateFromString(datestring[row]["time"]!)
let finalFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
finalFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
cell.textField?.stringValue = finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow!)
```

I try to change the string to time format but crash

Comment: mention the string that you are converting to date.

Comment: @iOS0709 you only need to scape the 'T'

Comment: Thanks for all got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(TxnTableData[row]["time"]!)
            // To convert the date into an HH:mm format
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
            let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
            print("time: \(dateString)")
```

I fixed this issue using this code I posted this answer Because in future it helps to others

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the value returned from datestring[row]["time"]!). Look at the sample below that uses hardcoded value.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'"

let dateShow = formatter.dateFromString("2015-12-17T10:27:02")

let finalFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
finalFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow!)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's works for me...

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'"
let dateShow : NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(datestring[row]["time"]!)
 formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
cell.textField?.text = finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow!) as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'"
 let dateShow = formatter.dateFromString("2015-12-19T08:20:21")
 let finalFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 finalFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
 finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow!)
 textField.text = finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow!) as String
```